# NavHostFragment Manager backstack is not proper

Tags: android, androidx, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am using navigation architecture component in my application.

Suppose I have fragment A as start destination.
I have push fragment B and Fragment C via navigation controller.

My navigation back stack is A-> B-> C.

Then I navigate to Fragment A with below action

```
<action
        android:id="@+id/fragment_A_type"
        app:destination="@id/fragment_a"
        app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_a"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

Now My navigation back stack should be A.

But if check
`parentFragmentManager.fragments` back stack is
A->A

Also the swipeBackDismiss of activity is not working.

my navigation.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FirstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.wearexample1.FirstFragment"
        android:label="@string/first_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/SecondFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.wearexample1.SecondFragment"
        android:label="@string/second_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">
    </fragment>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_activity_type"
        app:destination="@id/FirstFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/FirstFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

</navigation>
```

Comment: You mean you go to A from C?

Comment: yes, I navigate from C to A.

Comment: From C to A using action instead of back key, right? Then according to your current setup, it's normal behavior. What's your expectation?

Comment: with `app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_a"`
        `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` 
old instance of fragment A should be removed and fragments stack should be A.
my expected behavior is that the fragment stack when i go from C to A should be just A.

Comment: And what do you get now?

Comment: now i am getting A->A

Comment: I don't understand what is "A->A". Can you describe more detailly.

Comment: parentFragmentManager.fragments is returning list of fragments as [Fragment A, Fragment A] but the expected result is [Fragment A]. as i have pop the fragment till A( Inclusive) using `app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_a"` `app:popUpToInclusive="true"`

Comment: Post your `navigation` file. I did this before but with no problem: https://youtu.be/LNyk_FEkZoA.

Comment: @SamChen i have updated my navigation file

Comment: That's weird, you have the same setup as me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65723391/3466808.